# Invalid Syntax with " 'packages': [ ]," when installing setup.py

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm new to programming and have spent the past few weeks studying python on my own. Most of the instruction has been from the resource "Learn Python the Hard Way".

Now to my problem, I just started working on a quiz that basically has you complete and install your own setup.py file. However, after spending some time understanding the file and trying to run it; I keep getting a 'Invalid Syntax' error on the second single quote here:

`'packages': [ ],`.

I've tried everything that I can think of such as removing all the single quotes from the variables on the left side, replacing the colons with equal signs, renaming certain files and folders, or a combination of the three. I've compared the code to other sites offering similar tutorials. which is where the previous ideas arose, and have searched in several places including Google and stackoverflow.com for solutions to this problem. However, so far I haven't found any posts related to this particular situation.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS as my operating system.

---

I have a screen shot of the problem, but i lack the reputation to post it here. : (

---

This code should be exactly like the code from "Learn Python the Hard Way"
and I have only altered the variables as instructed, such as the name or email address.

## Heres the code from 'setup.py'

```
try:  
    from setuptools import setup  
except ImportError:  
    from distutils.core import setup  

config = {
    'description': 'Amateur Remake of the Clannad Visual Novel',  
    'author': 'Kristopher Anders',  
    'url': 'Unavailable Online.',  
    'download_url': 'Not Available online.',  
    'author_email': 'kanders91@gmail.com',  
    'version': '0.1',  
    'install_requires': ['nose']  
    'packages': ['seen0414'],  
    'scripts': [],  
    'name': 'Clannad Visual Novel'  
}  

setup(**config)
```

---

## Heres the file-tree for 'setup.py'

```
|---Clannad    \\root directly for 'setup.py' \\
      |---bin  
      |---docs  
      |---seen0414  
          |---__init__.py    --\\contents is exact copy of 'seen0414.py'\\  
          |---__init__.pyc        \\otherwise '__init__.py' was empty.\\
          |---module0414.py  --\\contains  functions for 'seen0414'\\  
          |---module0414.pyc
          |---script0414.txt --\\contains necessary text for 'module0414.py'\\  
          |---seen0414.py    --\\original(main) script\\  
      |---tests  
          |---clannad_tests.py  
          |---clannad_tests.pyc  
          |---__init__.py  
          |---__init__.pyc  
      |---setup.py
```

---

I'm sure its probably a very simple solution, but i just can't seem to figure this one out.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Thanks for asking such a clear question with plenty of supporting information.

Comment: Thanks, this site can be somewhat intimidating. So I wanted to make sure I did as much as I possibly could, beforehand.

Comment: it would be fine for you to login to [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and provide your experience for us to use this and improve the response that new users get :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
'install_requires': ['nose']
```

Is missing the `,`

Try

```
'install_requires': ['nose'],
```

Comment: Ya a "," was all it was. Thanks, it worked perfectly afterwards.

Comment: Now I finally get it. I looked for a way to mark it complete, but couldn't find till now...